# Apex Trigger Adding <p> character on newly inserted record from ChatterPost

Tags: apex, trigger, chatter

Created a trigger on `FeedItem` where it creates a new record on a custom object called `Internal Request`. I've mapped the `Body` of the Chatter post to the `Description__c` field in the `Internal Request` custom object. It is mapping correctly, except that it adds `<p>` before and after the body content of the chatter post into the `Description__c` field on the newly inserted `Internal Request` record.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can remove the `<p>`?

```
for(FeedItem cg : lGroupFeed){

                Ops_Priority_List__c i = new Ops_Priority_List__c(
                    OwnerId = mpostUserId.get(cg.Id),  
                    Description__c = cg.Body + '   ' + URL.getSalesforceBaseURL().toExternalForm() + '/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F93B0000004VGm&fld=' +cg.Id,   
                    Name = 'Questions from Chatter',   
                    Status__c = 'New', 
                    RecordTypeId = internalRequestQuestionRecordTypeId); 
                    newIRtoInsert.add(i); 
        }
```

[image: Screenshot of the ChatterPost]

[image: Screenshot of new record inserted]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to strip all HTML tags, there is a method for that. Seems like the simplest solution here:

```
String description = '';
if (cg.Body != null) description += cg.Body.stripHtmlTags();
description += // build url here;
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason those tags are included is because the post is created with Rich Text enabled. Chatter post relies on the HTML tags in the body to preserve the rich text info.

If you don't want to have the tags in your custom object, you can use the stripHtmlTags() function as Adrian suggested. But depends on what you do with the custom object, you might want to keep the tags if it will get rendered as html later.

You can also turn Rich Text off from the Settings so posts cannot be created with rich text info.